# Specify the type of the output of a Calculator filter

Tags: paraview

It seems as though the result of a Calculator filter is always a double array. Is there a way to change this type? For example, if I create a Sphere Source, then use a Calculator filter with the following:

```
1*iHat + 2*jHat + 0*kHat
```

I get an array that could theoretically be used to color the points (i.e. it is interpretable as RGB 3-vectors), but it is of type 'double' so Paraview cannot use it for coloring (without color mapping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of ParaView 5.1.2, and perhaps earlier versions, you can actually interpret 3-tuple arrays of doubles as colors the way you describe. Color values are specified in the range [0, 1] for double and float arrays instead of [0, 255] for unsigned char arrays.

To show these Calculator-defined colors without color mapping, color by the Calculator output array, then uncheck the option `Map Scalars` in the Properties panel.